Avoid lost wakeups in lock-free multi-producer single-consumer scenario
I have a number of threads that produce small pieces of data I’d like to process. It is important that I do not delay these threads by a lot, so processing should happen on another thread (a single worker-thread is sufficient, and it will probably have nothing to do >90% of the time).
Suspending the data threads while waiting for a mutex is too much of a delay for me, but I can live with delays on the worker thread. I therefore chose to go with the following solution:
I use a lock-free MPSC queue on which I push the data in the data threads.
The worker thread processes all work packages and then goes to sleep using a condition variable. The data threads notify the condition variable when new data is available.
The code is roughly as follows:
std::mutex mutex_;
std::condition_variable cv_;
MpscJobQueue queue_;

// worker thread
while (true) {
  while (!queue_.empty()) {
    process(queue_.pop());
  }
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
  cv_.wait(lock);
}

// data thread
queue_.push(myData);
cv_.notify_one();

This works pretty well most of the time, but there is a problematic corner case. When no more data packages are created, one (or maybe even several) package might stay on the queue, never being process because of a lost wakeup. This can happen in the following way:

The worker thread exits the inner while loop because the queue is empty
The data thread pushes a new work package
The data thread notifies the condition variable
The worker thread goes to sleep in cv_.wait(lock).

I understand that I could solve the problem of lost wakeups by acquiring a lock in the data thread before notifying the condition variable. But this might force the data threads to sleep, which I need to avoid.
Another way is to use something cv_.wait_for(lock, 1s); in the worker thread. This is the solution I’m currently using as data packages won’t remain unprocessed. If there’s no better way I could live with this solution, but it doesn’t feel great. Ideally, I’d like to avoid having these 1s delays from time to time.
Is there anything I’m missing? Is there a better way to avoid lost wakeups here without having to acquire a lock on the data threads?
Maybe using a spin lock together with std::condition_variable_any could be another solution? There would probably only be a very small amount of busy-waiting in both worker and data threads, so it sounds like this might be acceptable as well.

What counts as delaying the producer threads by a lot, for you? The slow part of using a mutex is the unlock->kernel->wake-up path, and if the consumer is ever to sleep, you need the kernel to wake it for you. If you can't afford a syscall at all, it needs to either poll (with a timer) or busy-wait.

Thanks for the suggestions. I solved the problem for myself in the following way: I realized that I have two different kinds of producers: 1. those for which performance matters a lot and I must avoid putting the thread to sleep and should avoid syscalls if possible.  And 2., those where locking a mutex, syscalls, or suspending the thread are actually acceptable. I realized that for the producers in group 1, I’m fine with missed wakeups, so I won’t lock the mutex there. In group 2, missed wakeups can be a problem, but I can just lock the mutex there to avoid the problem.

Finding a way to weaken the requirements is often the best optimization :)

It will be extremely hard to get away without using a mutex, but you can of course do all the processing outside of the mutex. I would code something like below, it is just a suggestion though.
std::mutex mutex_;
std::condition_variable cv_;
MpscJobQueue queue_;
bool waiting = false;

// worker thread
while (true) {
  while (!queue_.empty()) {
    process(queue_.pop());
  }
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
  if (!queue_.empty())
     continue;
  waiting = true;
  cv_.wait(lock);
}

// data thread
bool was_waiting;
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    was_waiting = waiting;
    waiting = false;
    queue_.push(myData);
}
if (was_waiting)
    cv_.notify_one();


Thanks for the suggestion. I can’t do that unfortunately though in the general case as I must avoid that the thread be suspended when the mutex is currently locked.
